# SharePoint Modern Web Part: News Web Part without links

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, sharepoint-news

Our customer asked us to create SharePoint Page.

They required to add only the text content which looks same as 'News' web part.

I tried text web part however, there are many differences between News and Text web part as below.

1. Text fonts and font size are difference between news and text
2. Vertical spaces in lines are also different
3. Underline colors are different
   [image]

Is there any way to change fonts and size and colors in out-of-the-box text web part?

Or is there any way to add news item without links?

It is unable to solve that requirement by myself and am really stacked.

Thank you so much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot add news without links in news web part as those are noting but SharePoint pages which are linked in news web part.

**Documentation**: [Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165)

You can change the font style, color and size in text web part with available OOTB options:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Add text, tables, and images to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)

---

If you are unable to match the exact font size & color using text web part, you cannot do much using SharePoint out of the box web parts.

In that case, you might need to develop custom web part using SPFx. Check:

1. [SharePoint-framework-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [sp-dev-fx-webparts samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts//tree/main/samples/)